# Build Path: Invalid ZIP archive

Tags: java, eclipse, build, path, zip

After searching for an answer to my problem in vain, I would be grateful if you guys could help me out.

I'm trying to add sounds to a little game I'm coding. I copy/paste the sound file in the Java project through eclipse, then go right click -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path.

Now this is how I learned it and haven't heard of any alternative so far, so I'm gonna guess this is the correct way to do it. However, as soon as I add it to the Build Path, I get an error saying "Invalid ZIP archive: soundname...".

First of all, why is it considered a ZIP file when it actually is a WAV file?
Should I add all of my files to an archive before adding them to the build path?

I tried changing my execution environment, upgrading it, upgrading eclipse, etc. but no success.

I think it's useful to add that I tried this method on my laptop and it works just fine. I just have no idea what is the problem.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Build path is for other code (libraries) to be included for compilation purposes. A WAV is not code, cannot be compiled/linked. A sound is a resource. You need to put it in `res/` folder, not in the build path.

`Invalid ZIP` error message is because Java libraries are actually ZIP files called JARs. So compiler was actually expecting a JAR file, but found a WAV, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, I was so sure my problem came from this that I didn't realize it wasn't. I mean, I solved the Invalid ZIP problem thanks to you, and also found my other problem. Apparently, my loops while(condition) //no instructions; don't work on my pc but work on my laptop. The loop is made to do nothing and wait for the user to enter a key to unlock it. On the PC, I have to use an instruction for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer but I have been stuck with the same problem and got it solve by doing the following:

Go to .`classpath` in your project and remove the .`java` class or any other file other than .`jar` that was added by mistake by the compiler. I am sure you were doing something like exclude/include from build path, this is a bug in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem stuck on it for a long time and i solved it by deleting one version of the same jar file.
so for me, there were 2 versions of the same jar 1.8 and 2.2 after deleting the 1.8 version and then going to maven -> update project solved it.